# output of scenario 1 to pass as input to scenario 2 in cucumber python

Tags: cucumber, python-behave

I would like to pass data from scenario 1 to scenario 2 are there any inbuilt methods exists?

scenario1: I am generating user with details

scenarioa2: I want to fetch generated user name from scenario1 and use in further steps

Comment: You can create separate method or function which you. can call in both scenarios

Comment: Not familiar with Behave, but for Cucumber generally the idea is for scenarios to be independent. Otherwise, if Scenario 1 fails, then Scenario 2 will also fail and you'll end up having to analyze a lot of failures... It's better for each test to test one only thing.

Comment: Given that the OP's scenarios are as he describes, you'd expect that combining the scenarios into one scenario would be the way to go, since fetching the user name already assumes the existence of the user. However, depending on *how* the user is being generated (i.e. perhaps if generation *"with details"* fails, then some default is created instead), there could be reason to separate these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Behave's `context` object to store data between test steps. For instance, let's say you have 2 scenarios:

```
Scenario: First one
    # Some Given's and stuff
    Then I am generating user with details

Scenario: Second one
    # Some Given's and stuff
    Then I fetch and use generated user details
```

In your step implementation file within the `steps/` directory:

```
@then("I am generating user with details")
def step_impl(context):
    context.user_details = function_to_generate_user_details()

@then("I fetch and use generated user details")
def step_impl(context):
    function_to_do_something(context.user_details)
```

Note that your step implementations do not have to be within the same file since Behave searches through all the files within the `steps/` directory when using your feature files.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of messing with logics of behave, you should save that data on excel data or any file, then parse that data on your other function.